# Polynomial equation: $P(\sin t) = P(\cos t)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $P(X)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients such that $P(\sin t) = P(\cos t), \, \forall t \in \mathbb R$.

Prove that there exists a unique polynomial $Q(Y)$ with real coefficients, such that $P(X) = Q(X^4-X^2)$.

(The converse is trivially true.)

**NOTE**:  This problem has almost nothing to do with trigonometry, despite appearances to the contrary. It's really about polynomials.

**Edit**:  It occurred to me I should add this - for full disclosure: I created this problem many years ago, for the math Olympiad in the East European country I grew up in; I am not looking for a solution for myself. I am offering it as a fun challenge to the math fans on this forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From $P(x)=P(\sqrt{1-x^2})$ we conclude $P$ is comprised of even powers, so $P(x)=L(x^2)$.

Now the condition reads $L(u)=L(1-u)$. Divide $L(u)$ by $u(1-u)$ to obtain quotient $q(u)$ and remainder $r(u)$. Substitute $L(u)=q(u)\,u(1-u)+r(u)$ into $L(u)=L(1-u)$ then reduce modulo $u(1-u)$ to obtain $au+b\equiv a(1-u)+b$, hence $a=0$. Then the functional equation descends to $q(u)=q(1-u)$ for the quotient $q$. Induct on degree to get $L(u)=Q(u(1-u))$.

Therefore $P(x)=L(x^2)=Q(x^2(1-x^2))$.

Comment: There is one more step to make this rigorous - the functional equation descending to $q$. Give it a moment's thought to understand that is not formally proved yet (although, of course, that step can be completed easily).

Comment: After finding the remainder is constant, substituting $L(u)=q(u)\,u(1-u)+r$ into $L(u)=L(1-u)$, we may subtract $r$ then divide by $u(1-u)$ to obtain $q(u)=q(1-u)$.

Comment: We need to be careful with the division, since we don't know it as polynomials, we only know it for u between 0 and 1 - and at 0 and at 1 we would be dividing by zero. But here, as well as in your argument where you found "a =0", what we can use is that if two polynomials have the same value for infinitely many "u" then they must be identically equal.

Comment: Yeah, good point.

Answer (score 1):

$P(\sin t) = P(\cos t)$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ implies that $P(x) = P(\sqrt{1 - x^2})$ for all $x \in [-1, 1]$, because for any $x \in [-1, 1]$ there is $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x = \sin(t)$ and $\sqrt{1-x^2} = \cos(t)$, and so  $P(x) = P(\sin(t)) = P(\cos(t)) = P(\sqrt{1-x^2})$.

Does it make it any easier for you? I can give you more hints if you need them.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading omission when I posted the problem; please see what I added.

Comment: Ah. It's OK if you ask me, but if I were you, I wouldn't be surprised if this question was closed because of this -- the rules on stackexchange websites can be weird sometimes...

Comment: Oh? I didn't realize that - is that easy to find in the rules? It is definitely not my intent to break the rules. With that said, that is a particularly odd rule; what, stack exchange is only for free solutions to others' homework and exam problems? It may be enough to make me leave this forum.

Comment: I haven't understand which rules you were speaking about. I have the same opinion as @mathguy. We are here for helping people (students in particular) AND have fun with problems even if they have been solved elsewere at the condition, of course, that they are interesting (it's the case here).

Comment: This problem has certainly not been solved online anywhere; it was used in our Olympiad, there was no web then, and I doubt there are more than a few people in the world who even remember this problem today. (If that is the possible concern.)

Comment: I'm pretty skeptical this has never been done on the internet before.

Comment: @arctictern - well, of course, it may have been (the problem pretty much begs to be "created") - but if so, I am almost certain it was an independent "creation" of the same problem. With that said, I just did a quick Google search on "P(sin t) = P(cos t)" - this brought up this here problem right at the top of search results, so Google knows how to read the search term, and nothing else related to this problem.

Comment: @user325968 - StackExchange actually encourages us to "answer our own questions" https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0):

We have $$P(-\sin t)=P(\sin t)$$ because $$P(- \sin t)=P(\sin (-t))=P(\cos (-t))=P(\cos t)=P(\sin t)$$ It follows that the polynomial $P$ is an even function since a polynomial of degree $n$ is completely determined by $n+1$ distinct points. Hence $P(x)$ have even exponents only.

On the other hand, it is easy to verify the following double identity:
$$\sin^4 t-\sin^2 t=\cos^4 t-\cos^2 t=-(\sin^2 t \cos^2 t)$$
Because of $P$ is an even function, one has $P(-(\sin x \cos x)^2)=P((\sin x \cos x)^2)$ so (to work with positive but not necessary) 
$$ P((\sin x \cos x)^2)=P(\sin^4 x-\sin^2 x)$$
The function $g(x)=(\sin x\cos x)^2$ is an even function of domain $\mathbb R$ which has a máximum equal to $\frac 14$ at each point $x=\frac{(1+2k)\pi}{4}$ .

We have 
$$P(g(X))=Q(X)=P(X^4-X^2)\qquad (*)$$ 
The equality of polynomials  $(*)$ is valid for all value $X=\sin t$ so is valid for all $X$.

FINAL NOTE.- We have proved that there is a polynomial $Q(X)$ such that $Q(X)=P(X^4-X^2)$ but the proposition ask about  $P(X)= Q(X^4-X^2)$ Are these two equalities equivalent or is there a typo?. Anyway,the relation $(*)$  is true.

Comment: This solution is correct up to a point, but then you write $P(g(X)) = Q(X)$. This introduces a notation (definition), for $Q(X)$; but $g(X)$ is not a polynomial, so there is no reason for $Q$ to be a polynomial. $Q$ is just some function. Also, how do you jump from $Q(X) = P(g(X))$ to $Q(X) = P(X^4-X^2)$?

Comment: Read the ligne at the end before FINAL NOTE, please. $(*)$ is a set of equalities, an infinite one, for which this relation is verified, so you can determine the coefficients of a polynomial. If, after this determination, $Q(X)$ is not a polynomial, then what is as a function?. Regards. (Maybe my weak English make my explanation to be deficient,it is a possibility)

Comment: No, it is not the language barrier. Imagine $P(X) = X^4 - X^2$. Then $Q(x)$ is the trigonometric function $Q(x) = (\sin x \cos x)^8 - (\sin x \cos x)^4$, which is definitely not a polynomial - for example because it is a periodic function, and polynomials - other than constants - are never periodic.

Comment: I stop here @mathguy. However I stop saying that, by $(*)$ the functions $Q$ and $P$ coincide over a non-countable set of points and $P$ is a polynomial, so $Q$ what can be?. Best regards.